# Correct way to force sales per month

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere

I am trying to analyse some sales information and I can't get the SQL query working. As I still learn how to use SQL properly, I probably just did not see the regular solution.

I want a list of all articles in our database and show the sales per month for each of them. Months without sale should be listed with a zero.

I have stored the article information in one table, the order information in another and in a third table the actual items sold.

My problem now is, that there seem to be empty somehow created I cannout filter.
Additionally, if I refer other tables with dates, the date values "mulitply" instead of joining to existing values/rows (leaving with 12 rows for each month in reportMonth).

This is my code:

```
//* list of months */
WITH dates(reportMonth) as (
    select 1 union all select 2 union all 
    select 3 union all select 4 union all 
    select 5 union all select 6 union all 
    select 7 union all select 8 union all 
    select 9 union all select 10 union all 
    select 11 union all select 12
    )


SELECT article.articleno AS 'article_no'
    , month(beleg.orderdate)
    , dates.reportMonth

    , ISNULL(sum(orders_pos.amount), 0)
        AS 'VK_amount'

FROM article
    CROSS JOIN dates
    LEFT JOIN orders_pos ON article.articleno = orders_pos.articleno
    LEFT JOIN orders ON orders_pos.beleg_id = orders.id 
        AND ISNULL(month(orders.orderdate), 0) != 0 
        AND month(orders.orderdate) = dates.reportMonth

GROUP BY article.artikelnr
    , month(orders.orderdate)
    , dates.reportMonth
```

This is the current output

```
article_no  month(beleg.orderdate)  reportMonth VK_amount
Produkt_A                               1              5
Produkt_A                               2              9
Produkt_A                               3              7
Produkt_A                               4              5
Produkt_A                               5              5
Produkt_A                               6              7
Produkt_A                               7              5
Produkt_A                               8              7
Produkt_A                               9              7
Produkt_A                               10             6
Produkt_A                               11             7
Produkt_A                               12             7
Produkt_A     1                         1              1
Produkt_A     4                         4              1
Produkt_A     5                         5              2
Produkt_A     7                         7              3
Produkt_A     8                         8              2
```

This is what I would need

```
article_no  month(beleg.orderdate)  reportMonth VK_amount
Produkt_A                           1           1
Produkt_A                           2           0
Produkt_A                           3           0
Produkt_A   4                       4           1
Produkt_A   5                       5           2
Produkt_A                           6           0
Produkt_A   7                       7           3
Produkt_A   8                       8           2
Produkt_A                           9           0
Produkt_A   10                      10          2
Produkt_A                           11          0
Produkt_A                           12          0
```

Does someone have an idea that may help here?
If you need more information to understand my case, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your query shouldn't work because the aggregation columns in the `GROUP BY` do not match the columns in the `SELECT`.  Perhaps the right query will help:

```
SELECT a.articleno AS article_no, month(o.orderdate), d.reportMonth,
       COALESCE(sum(op.amount), 0) as VK_amount
FROM article a CROSS JOIN 
     dates d LEFT JOIN
     orders_pos op
     ON a.articleno = op.articleno LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON op.beleg_id = o.id AND
        month(o.orderdate) = d.reportMonth  -- is there a condition on year?
GROUP BY a.artikelnr, month(o.orderdate), d.reportMonth
ORDER BY a.artikelnr, month(o.orderdate), d.reportMonth
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
In the `GROUP BY` was a typo, indeed, from putting this example together. I have edited this in my text.
A year condition is not necessary here, as I select for a specific range of dates in a `WHERE` statement, which is not needed for this example.